# Why does this command get a value once?

Tags: c

```
    while (1){
        scanf("%c", &input);
            if((input>='a')&&(input<='z')) {
                count[input-'a']++;
            }
            else if((input>='A')&&(input<='Z')) {
                count[input-'A']++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
    }
```

Why does this command get a value once? Doesn't while(1) mean infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

`break` causes the loop to break thus not running again.

Remove it so the `while` loop will occur again.

Answer (score 1):

`break` exit a `while` whatever the condition in the `while`.

You did not show what you input in the question. However according to the behaviour you observe, it's not a letter or a uppercase letter, thus you end up breaking the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

When you give an input, even if it is a character, it also reads a 'newline' character as you press enter to pass that. So after every letter, a newline is automatically read and so loop breaks.
Try

```
scanf("%c%*c", &input);
```

It will remove that excess newline character.